# pgadmin installation error while compiling from source

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to build pgadmin 1.20 from source. I already have 1.20.0 installed.

Anyway, I followed the script from INSTALL file. This is where I'm stuck:

```
make    
./pgadmin/ui/embed-xrc
Rebuilding xrcdialogs.cpp...    
wxrc: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    
diff: ./pgadmin/ui/xrcDialogs.cpp.new: No such file or directory    
mv: cannot stat ‘./pgadmin/ui/xrcDialogs.cpp.new’: No such file or directory    
Makefile:1024: recipe for target 'xrc' failed make: *** [xrc] Error 1
```

I tried reconfiguring to wxGTK-2.8.12 version

```
./configure –prefix=/usr/local/WX --with-gtk --enable-gtk2 --enable-unicode.
```

I got the same message. I tried deleting everything and starting from scratch,using pgadmin 1.20. I tried reinstalling wxGTK 2.8.12. All in vain.

Any ideas where I should start looking?

Comment: Did you put `–` (instead of `--`) and the trailing `.` in your `configure` command. Please try again without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `libxml2` and `libxslt` if you have not already.

You should make sure that you have the library files for `libwx_baseu_xml` in `/usr/local/lib` or somewhere in your computer. Also make sure that this location of `libwx_baseu_xml` is in the library search path in `/etc/ld.so.conf`

You can update the libraries by simply executing the following command:

> `sudo ldconfig`

In most cases this should solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, it's working but when i gave command  "sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib" then it giving output as "libpcp.so is not a symbolic link" what does it mean..

Comment: I guess there must be multiple `libpcp.so` files. You can remove the problematic`libpcp.so` and make symlink to the other `libpcp.so.<version>` file.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [Ron's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/641178/474660), you may also use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to temporarily set additional paths for the dynamic linker to search the shared libraries in non-standard locations:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
          A  list of directories in which to search for ELF libraries at
          execution-time.  The items in the list are separated by either
          colons  or  semicolons.  Similar to the PATH environment vari‐
          able.  This variable is ignored in secure-execution mode.
```

(adapted from `ld.so(8)` manpage)

Thus the following command should work, without running `ldconfig` as superuser:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/WX/lib ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/WX --with-gtk --enable-gtk2 --enable-unicode
```